# Ldap connect fails in php

Tags: php, ldap, cas, saml-2.0, simplesamlphp

At first, sorry for my English.

I'm currently installing the newest version of simplesamlphp (an unknown tool 'till now for me + I'm a Java developer (not php) so my knowledge on php is limited).

The main aim is to use CAS with SAML2 using simplesamlphp.

The problem is... on CAS.php module file we have a call to 'new SimpleSAML_Auth_LDAP(...)' which is supposed to create a connection to the ldap server, but it fails and shows no error (just a blank page). I tracked the error to the ../lib/SimpleSAML/Auth/LDAP.php file constructor; it fails when it tries to connect to the ldap:

```
$this->ldap = @ldap_connect($hostname, $port);
```

Any idea about it?

Comment: Are you sure you're providing the right hostname and port for your ldap server? You can use the PHP manual's first example for ldap_connect as a simple test script. Just provided your settings and see if you can connect. http://php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-connect.php

Comment: I'm sure at 100% that hostname is correct and 90% that port is so too. I've even tried connecting securely to LDAP server which should run with no error as it's working on a Java app. I guess it may something else :S

Comment: What do you provide as hostname and port?

Comment: Are you using LDAP over SSL (aka LDAPS) or regular LDAP? If you are using LDAPS make sure your client (the PHP app) trusts the LDAP server certificate.

Comment: I finally managed to make it run, i just had to reinstall php5-ldap, seems that something went wrong the first time it was installed.

Now I found another problem and it's that when validating the username:
    $ldap->validate($this->_ldapConfig, $username);
I get another error: unauthenticated bind (DN with no password) disallowed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to make it run, i just had to reinstall php5-ldap, seems that something went wrong the first time it was installed. Now I have more doubts about how it really works, but the post is resolved.